# Copying a compressed file from S3 to redshift (stl-load-error)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy data from S3 to amazon redshift by Python script

````
command = 

    ("COPY {qualname}\n"
                "FROM 's3://{keypath}' \n"
                "CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={key};aws_secret_access_key={secret}' "
                "{gzip} "
                "{null_as} "
                #"{emptyasnull}"
                "CSV IGNOREHEADER 1;").format(qualname=qualname,
                                 keypath=url,
                                 key=aws_access_key_id,
                                 secret=aws_secret_access_key,
                                 gzip="GZIP " if compress else " ",
                                 null_as="NULL AS '{}'".format(null_as) if null_as is not None else "",
                                 emptyasnull="EMPTYASNULLL " if emptyasnull else " ")```
````

- `keypath` is s3://{bucket - name}/daily-sku-benefits/2018-12-27
- `qualname` is the table name

However I am getting an error:

> (psycopg2.InternalError) Load into table 'daily_sku_benefits' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.
>    [SQL: "COPY daily_sku_benefits\nFROM 's3://{bucket - name}/daily-sku-benefits/2018-12-27.csv.gzip' \nCREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={access key};aws_secret_access_key={secret-key} GZIP   CSV IGNOREHEADER 1;"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)

And on checking `stl_load_error` I am getting this error:

```
Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]
```

Does anybody have any idea about it?

Comment: when you cannot guarantee the integrity of the values,   load these timestamps into a varchar first then post process them.

Comment: What was the format of the date it tried to load?

Comment: `envar_date_string = os.environ.get(key='BILL_DATE',default=datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))`
`envar_date = datetime.strptime(envar_date_string, "%Y-%m-%d")`
`billing_date = datetime(envar_date.year, envar_date.month, envar_date.day)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error clearly shows you the way to resolve the issue, your `timestamp` data must be of format `[YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]`.

Your data should look like below (I have separator as pipe(|), though , is fine too),

```
 Column1|Columnd2|created_at
 Test1|Test description1|2018-05-10 23:54:51
 Test2|Test description2|2018-05-17 22:15:53
```

For example table with structure-

```
create table daily_sku_benefits(
Colunm1 varchar(55),
Colunm2 varchar(255),
updated_at timestamp);
```

One more trick you could apply, because it might be possible that you complete data might not be `bad`, it may be `some percentage`, Hence you could use `MAXERROR` property in `Copy` command. Here goes [Maxerror](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror) explanation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have 6 date columns with datatype as timestamp without time zone and one columns with datatype as  date ... Can that be the problem?

Comment: Not at all, if you think about it, as you put a separator between the data `|` or `,`, its all together different data-point then, and one doesn't get mixed with other. But obviously, you may have to do some additional testing and some fixing on your end to make sure everything goes well.